# How can I configure Go with Docker Compose such that the main.go file is in /cmd folder

Tags: docker, go, docker-compose

I've been getting this error when I have `main.go` in `/cmd` folder rather than root:

```
| building...
| no Go files in /app
| failed to build, error: exit status 1
```

This is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM golang:1.22.1-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN go mod download

RUN go build -o main .

CMD ["/app/main"]
```

This is my `docker-compose.yaml` file:

```
version: "3"

services:
  main:
    container_name: myapp
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    ports:
      - ${GRPC_PORT}:9090
      - ${REST_PORT}:8080
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    develop:
    watch:
      - action: rebuild
        files:
          - ./**/*.go
          - ./go.mod
          - ./go.sum
```

I've tried many things todo with volumes and working directories but cannot see how to build and execute from the `cmd` folder.

Comment: "/app" is simply not "/cmp", but I don't see "/cmd" anywhere in your code or the error message. Is the above really the code or error message you're getting? Please extract a [mcve]. Also, I don't think Docker Compose needs to be involved, since the error is just from building.

Comment: A note on the Compose file: the `volumes:` block hides everything in the image's `/app` directory, including the `/app/main` binary you're hoping the Dockerfile will build.  This is unnecessary, particularly since Go is a compiled language and you don't need the application source at runtime.  Deleting the `volumes:` block won't fix the build issue, but it will fix a "not found" error when you go to run the container.

Comment: Deleting the volume would prevent live reload while editing files on my local machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM golang:latest

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app

RUN go get github.com/githubnemo/CompileDaemon
RUN go install github.com/githubnemo/CompileDaemon

ENTRYPOINT CompileDaemon --build="go build -o tmp/main cmd/main.go" --command=./tmp/main
```

`docker-compose.yaml`

```
version: "3"
services:
  app:
    build: .
    container_name: go-docker-live-reload
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
```

Here's an example repo and explanation article:

- https://github.com/clintvidler/go-docker-live-reload
- https://vidler.app/blog/golang/live-reloading-go-with-docker-compose/

Comment: Please, in your answers try to provide solutions, not links. If you want to recommend links just add a comment in the question.

Comment: I've edited my answer according to your suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

I assume that by "I have `main.go` in `/cmd` folder rather than root" you mean that your project is structured something like this:

```
├── cmd
│   ├── go.mod
│   └── main.go
├── docker-compose.yml
└── Dockerfile
```

In that case this should work:

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM golang:1.22.1-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY cmd/ .

RUN go mod download

RUN go build -o main .

CMD ["/app/main"]
```

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3"

services:
  main:
    container_name: myapp
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
```

`main.go` (A placeholder for your `main.go`.)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, World!")
}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh you're right, my config also works if I remove:


    volumes:
      - .:/app/cmd


The volume must be overwriting. 

Not yet sure how to mount the volume as well so that hot reload can work.

Comment: Hmmm. If you are wanting hot reload to work then perhaps you should not be doing `go build` at build time (ie. in the `Dockerfile`)?